# Windows script to backup specific files from directory to another on same machine

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup

I need a help with mine school project scipt. I thought it would be easy, but apparently found myself a bit confused with it.

The task is to:
Write a script, which gets as parameters two directories. First directory must exist. From the first directory and its subfolders the backup will be done for files such as .c,.txt,.jpg,.csv... and these files will be backed up to the second directory, which is nonexistent or is empty.

I figured out just the copying part...

```
@echo

if %username%==administrator goto useradmin

rem # files with C 
XCOPY "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\iT universe city\Source Folder\*.c" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\jpg\" /D /I /S /Y

rem # files with TXT 
XCOPY "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\iT universe city\Source Folder\*.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\jpg\" /D /I /S /Y

rem # files with JPG
XCOPY "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\iT universe city\Source Folder\*.jpg" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\jpg\" /D /I /S /Y

rem # files with CSV
XCOPY "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\iT universe city\Source Folder\*.csv" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\jpg\" /D /I /S /Y
```

Comment: Can you enunciate which parts are missing?

Comment: Are you providing the script with the parameters when starting the script? `%1 %2`. Or are you expecting the end user to provide them in running? `Set/P "SrcDir=Enter Source Folder: "` and `Set/P "DstDir=Enter Destination Folder: "`

Comment: I think the parameters should be provided at the start of the script.

Comment: What exactly isn't working - please show some error messages...

Comment: It is not that this part isn´t working. I dont know how to formulate the parameters at the start and the conditions. I had only 3 lessons of batch and I pretty much don´t know how it is supposed to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't usually provided homework/tasks for which you have not previously been provided sufficient information. When you are the intention is usually that you actually put in some time and effort researching.

For that reason I will only provide this. You can put in your own time and effort to look up the commands and work out how it works:

```cmd
@Echo Off
Set/P "SrcDir=Enter Source Folder: "
If Not Exist "%SrcDir%\" Exit/B
Set/P "DstDir=Enter Destination Folder: "
ROBOCOPY "%SrcDir%" "%DstDir%" *.c *.txt *.jpg *.csv /S
```

Comment: @KibaBredley You'll have to iterate the extensions to sort them into different dest foilders. `For %%A in (.c .txt .jpg .csv) do Echo Robocopy "%SrcDir%\*.%%A" "%DestDir%\%%A\"` Look at the output before removing the echo

Comment: @LotPings, just bear in mind that their example put them all in the same destination directory too and they admitted to that part working! and Kiba, it is recommended that you mark correct answers as such so that the site works as intended.

Comment: You need to scroll the code to see there are different subfolders addressed.

Comment: @LotPings They're all going into "%UserProfile%\Desktop\jpg"!

Comment: Agreed, but I'm shure not with intention.